# What is the speed of $x^2/\sin^2x$ tends to $1$?

Tags: inequality

$$1+\frac{x^2}{3}\leq\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x}\leq 1+(1-\frac{4}{\pi^2})x^2,x\in [0,\pi/2]?$$

How to prove this? I know just the $x^2$, but $1/3$, and $1-4/\pi^2$ is not known.

And it is the finest inequality we can obtain.

Comment: This is not true at $x=\pi$.  Are you just looking near $x=0$?

Comment: What is your source?

Comment: It should be $x\in [0,\pi/2]$.

Answer (score 2):

General approach for all such local inequalities.

Compare Taylor series.

Alternatively (or equivalently), take derivatives and use the criterions for monotonicity using derivatives.

Example: You are proving that $f(x)\geq0$ for $x$ near zero. Assume that $f(0)=0$ and that $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)>0$. Then, locally $f(x)\geq0$.

The conclusion can also be obtained if $f''(0)=f'''(0)=0$ but $f^{IV}(0)=0$. ...

**Example:**

In this problem we have:
$$\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}=1+\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{2x^6}{189}+\frac{x^8}{675}+O(x^9).$$

From this we get that

$$\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}-(1+\frac{x^3}{3})=\frac{2x^6}{189}+\frac{x^8}{675}+O(x^9).$$

This shows that $$\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}-(1+\frac{x^3}{3})$$ is locally, near $x=0$, like $2x^6/189$ and therefore non-negative. This proves 
$$1+\frac{x^3}{3}\leq \frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}.$$

Let us try the other. From the Taylor expansion above we get:
$$1+(1-\frac{4}{\pi^2})x^2-\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}=(1-\frac{4}{\pi^2})x^2-\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{2x^6}{189}-\frac{x^8}{675}+O(x^9).$$

This shows that locally, near $x=0$, $1+(1-\frac{4}{\pi^2})x^2-\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}$ is like $(1-\frac{4}{\pi^2})x^2$. Since $1-4/\pi^2>0$, we get that $$0\leq1+(1-\frac{4}{\pi^2})x^2-\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)},$$
near $x=0$. It works!

Comment: However, it does not work in this case....

Comment: He! Let me see. I didn't even check.

Comment: I added the computation to the answer. I guess it does work.

Comment: But how can we prove this inequality for all $x\in [0,\pi/2]$, not just a local one?